# Partitioning one side of a bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a bipartite graph of entities and weighted classifications. Here's a trivial example - "A" and "B" are entities; "road bike" and "bike" are classifications. 
[image: options]

I want to partition my entities by assigning them a classification to maximize sum(edge weights from entities to their classification) - sum(edge weights from entities to classifications used in the partition the entities were not assigned to.)

The second part - the weights between entities and the classifications I am using, but not for those entities - is really important to be because it quantifies the idea that combination of classifications chosen should partition the entities as unambiguously as possible.

Here are the potential partitions for entities in my example, ranked in score order.
The weights for the second parts - between entities and the classifications in the partition they are related to but not "classified" as are dotted gray lines.
[image]

Is the problem I'm describing known under a different name, and are their solutions (or approximations) for it?

Comment: It's weird that classes which do not have any instances do not count towards the score.